# postgreSQL error creating a table with reference

Tags: postgresql

New to joins, constraints, and references in PostgreSQL,

Here are the two table schemas I'm trying to create. The instructors table works just fine. The instructor_profile throws all sorts of errors.

```
create table instructors (
    id serial primary key,
    auth0id text unique not null,
    name varchar(30) not null,
    email varchar(100) unique not null
);

create table instructor_profile (
    id serial primary key,
    instructor_id integer references instructors(id),                                       
    age integer not null,   
    gender varchar(10) not null,
    price integer(10,2) not null,
    imgUrl text not null,
    about text not null,
    yearsTeaching integer not null,
    acoustic boolean,
    electric boolean,
    latitude text,
    longitude text
);
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Please post them in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just making a mistake defining the type of the price column, replace this line with:

```
price decimal(10,2) not null,
```

this notation `(10,2)` is used to specify the precision of decimal types and you are trying to use it with the integer type.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome = ). Just so you know, here we try to avoid comments like thank you and others not related to the question. Also can you accept my answer ? Cheers.